# Make test task for kotlin incremental in Gradle?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, incremental-build

I would like to make my `test` task incremental, but I noticed that it looks for files in `java` instead of `kotlin`:

```
Task ':test' is not up-to-date because:
  Task.upToDateWhen is false.
file or directory '/path/to/my/project/build/classes/java/test', not found
```

I have the following plugins enabled:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.20"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.20"
}
```

How I can configure test task to pick up `/path/to/my/project/build/classes/kotlin/test`
instead of `java`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like IntelliJ IDEA sets `Task.upToDateWhen` to `false`. In console it works fine.

There is a bug for that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-240111